# count how many rows in database and display them

Tags: php, mysql

I developed quiz application in **PHP**. i have questions table in my database..so i display only one question per page.so when user click on next button i display next question from my database randomly..

So the problem is when user reached to last question i want to change the button name to finish automatically without click on the button.

**For Example:** if i have 10 questions in my database when user reached 9th question and click on next button we need to display 10th question button as finish instead of next.

How to do this?

This is my count Query:

```
$nRows = $dbh->query('select count(*) from questions')->fetchColumn(); 
echo $nRows;
```

This is my next button:

```
<button  class="submit-btn Next"  
         id="refreshButton" 
         data-id="<?php echo $value->id ?>" 
         name="<?php echo $key ?>" 
         onclick="change_next(this.value)" 
         value="<?php echo $key ?>">
   Next
</button>
```

Comment: This depends on knowing what question you're on and comparing it to the count you're getting from the database.

Comment: yeah..but how can we get from  databse..can you please tell me

Comment: I don't know. You haven't given much code to work from. If you gave each question a sequence identifier this would be a lot easier, or even better, a sequence and count column pair. Entry `10,10` would be trivial to detect.

Comment: @tadman can you please explain briefly..i can't understand..

Comment: Alter your schema and add in columns to represent the sequence of each question in the list. You could do this with a singular column containing strings of the form `x/y`. Where `x==y` then you know you're on the last question. So entry one is `1/10`, and the last is `10/10`. You can populate these by hand if necessary, or automatically if you can figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can keep a separate counter to count questions displayed.

simple algo:

```
eg : questions = 10 #consider 
     counter = 1
     while counter != questions:
          displayquestion_using_random_function();
          counter = counter + 1

     if counter == questions:
          change_the_button_to_finish()
```

Comment: That doesn't really work. You need to track this from page to page.

Comment: You're partially right there, but you don't show how that might work, so this isn't a complete answer.

Comment: i think using session will work here, instead of updating value in database